# Parsing a json object to string values in Java

Tags: java, json, solr

I'm not able to parse my json object to get all the values from the field "titleText" from a SOLR execution in Java code :-(

Could anyone help me, please?

```
{"responseHeader":{"status":0,"QTime":0,"params":{"start":"0","q":"USA","wt":"json","rows":"2"}},"response":{"numFound":143833,"start":0,"docs":[{"id":"4180409","titleText":"US-amerikanische Badmintonmeisterschaft","userId":264581,"user":"Florentyna"},{"id":"283110","titleText":"USA TODAY","userId":19578,"user":"Catrin"}]}}
```

Comment: Why are you "not able"? What have you tried? Are you using a JSON parsing library? Did you get compiler errors or runtime errors? If so, then what are the errors?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried a JSON parser implemented in Java ? [Different](http://www.json.org/java/) [implementations](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome) [exist](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), each with their pros/cons.

Comment: Which one ? There are 3 linked in. I don't think anyone can answer your issue of 'not being luck', unfortunately